# Zeleny algorithm in Python / Sage

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, python, sagemath

**Question.**
Are there any recommended or, at least, known implementations of [Zeleny multi-objective simplex method (MSA)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2629823) in Python, especially Sage?

**Side-note.**
I have found [standard simplex implementations](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/numerical/sage/numerical/interactive_simplex_method.html) and several [linear programming backends](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/numerical/index.html#linear-optimization-lp-and-mixed-integer-linear-optimization-mip-solver-backends), but none of these, as far as I know, implement extended simplex algorithm for multi-criteria case.

Comment: If you haven't already, it might be worth putting this question on ask.sagemath.org